# Avoid Intersection Observer to observe 2 targets at time

Tags: javascript, html, intersection-observer

I have some sections and some navigation links in my page. Im using Intersection Observer to add an `active` class to a respective link that redirect to this section. In some part of my page, 2 sections are visibles i want to add the `active` class to the most visible section (only once at time) but i don't know how:

[image]

Here is the Intersection Observer code:

```
    const sectObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    for (entry of entries) {
      // here i get the section id and the link classList:
      const { id } = entry.target,
      { classList } = document.querySelector(`#to-${id}`);
      if (entry.intersectionRatio) {
        classList.add('active');
      } else {
        classList.remove('active');
      };
    };
  });
```

And here the instance of the targets observer:

```
    document.querySelectorAll('section:not(#get-cv, #skills)')
      .forEach(link => sectObserver.observe(link));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#creating_an_intersection_observer) has a `threshold` option which defines how much of a section (from 0 to 1) needs to be visible before it runs your function. Try to get this percentage right for the sections on your page.

```js
const options = { threshold: 0.5 };
const sectObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  for (entry of entries) {
    // here i get the section id and the link classList:
    const { id } = entry.target,
    { classList } = document.querySelector(`#to-${id}`);
    if (entry.intersectionRatio) {
      classList.add('active');
    } else {
      classList.remove('active');
    };
  };
}, options);
```